# Installation of GhostView needed before installing MiKTeX?

Tags: installing, miktex

I want to install MiKTeX 2.9.3959 (on WinXP in order to create PS files).

Do I need (or better, should I) install GhostScript and GhostView first, before installing MiKTeX?

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Answer (score 2):

Ghostscript is required by MiKTeX utilities like epstopdf, and is included in the MiKTeX distribution.

Comment: But it does not install GostView.

Comment: If you'd like to view PS files under Windows, you would need something like gsview. You can get it at http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/get49.htm